# Web scraping in R using for loop

Tags: r, loops, web-scraping

I would like to scrape the data from [this link](http://search.beaconforfreedom.org/search/censored_publications/result.html?author=&cauthor=&title=&country=7327&language=&censored_year=&censortype=&published_year=&censorreason=&sort=t&page), and I have written the following code in R to do so. This, however, does not work and only returns the first page of the results. Apparently, the loop does not work. Does anybody know what's wrong with the loop?

```
library('rvest')

for (i in 1:40) {

     webpage <- read_html(paste0(("http://search.beaconforfreedom.org/search/censored_publications/result.html?author=&cauthor=&title=&country=7327&language=&censored_year=&censortype=&published_year=&censorreason=&sort=t&page=, i"))

     rank_data_html <- html_nodes(webpage,'tr+ tr td:nth-child(1)')

     rank_data <- html_text(rank_data_html)

     rank_data<-as.numeric(rank_data)

     title_data_html <- html_nodes(webpage,'.censo_list font')

     title_data <- html_text(title_data_html)

     author_data_html <- html_nodes(webpage,'.censo_list+ td font')
     author_data <- html_text(author_data_html)

     country_data_html <- html_nodes(webpage,'.censo_list~ td:nth-child(4) font')

     rcountry_data <- html_text(country_data_html)

     year_data_html <- html_nodes(webpage,'tr+ tr td:nth-child(5) font')

     year_data <- html_text(year_data_html)

     type_data_html <- html_nodes(webpage,'tr+ tr td:nth-child(6) font')

     type_data <- html_text(type_data_html)

}

censorship_df<-data.frame(Rank = rank_data, Title = title_data, Author = author_data, Country = rcountry_data, Type = type_data, Year = year_data)

write.table(censorship_df, file="sample.csv",sep=",",row.names=F)
```

Comment: Scraping that page is disallowed on [its robots.txt](http://search.beaconforfreedom.org/robots.txt)

Comment: You are over writing the variables on each iteration of the loop.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure there's anything wrong with the loop?  I would expect it to get the first page of results 40 times.  Look at

```
webpage <- read_html(paste0(("http://search.beaconforfreedom.org/search/censored_publications/result.html?author=&cauthor=&title=&country=7327&language=&censored_year=&censortype=&published_year=&censorreason=&sort=t&page=, i"))
```

Shouldn't that be (difference in the last ten characters of the string; the quotation mark moves)

```
webpage <- read_html(paste0(("http://search.beaconforfreedom.org/search/censored_publications/result.html?author=&cauthor=&title=&country=7327&language=&censored_year=&censortype=&published_year=&censorreason=&sort=t&page=", i))
```

What `paste0` does in R is it stitches together two strings without any separator.  But you only have one string.  So it tries to fetch results for `page=, i`.  But you want it to fetch `page=1` through `page=40`.  So put the quotation mark like `page=", i` so that it pastes the URL and `i` together.

I'm not an R programmer, but that simply leaps out at me.

[Source](https://www.r-bloggers.com/difference-between-paste-and-paste0/) for `paste0` behavior.